# MySQL update script throws PDOException

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

**Question solved... silly mistake**

i have a little problem with my database update script (i'm using PDO and included a [PDO class from here](https://github.com/d89/database))

My logic:

Click on submit button calls "editClient.php" (need this cause i use AJAX):

```
<?php
// include clients class
require("../classes/clients.class.php");

// get vars & save them in $values array
$id = $_POST['id'];
$id = (int)$id;
$name = $_POST['name'];
$initial = $_POST['initial'];
$payment = $_POST['payment'];
$hourly_rate = $_POST['hourly-rate'];
if ($payment == 'payment-per-service') {
    $hourly_rate = "";
}
$active = $_POST['active'];

$values = array($name,$initial,$payment,$hourly_rate,$active,$id);

$client = new Client();
$client->editClient($values);
?>
```

My client.class.php (shorten):

```
<?php
// include database class
require_once('../../../lib/php/classes/database/database.class.php');

class Client {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = Database::get("default");
    }

    public function editClient($values) {
        if ($this->db->update("UPDATE clients SET name=?, initial=?, payment=?, hourly_rate=?, active=? WHERE cid=?",$values)) {
        } else {
            print "Updating failed";
        }
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->db = null;
        unset($this->db);
    }   
}
?>
```

But every time i call my edit client script, i get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'PDO-Exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1' in /home/www/gopeter/collab/lib/php/classes/database/database.class.php:104 

Stack trace: 
#0 /home/www/gopeter/collab/lib/php/classes/database/database.class.php(127): Database->_query('UPDATE clients ...', Array, 'update') 
#1 /home/www/gopeter/collab/sites/clients/classes/clients.class.php(24): Database->update('UPDATE clients ...', Array) 
#2 /home/www/gopeter/collab/sites/clients/ajax/editClient.php(20): Client->editClient(Array) #3 {main} thrown in /home/www/gopeter/collab/lib/php/classes/database/database.class.php on line 104
```

But my SQL query looks correct?

Comment: BTW: This makes your code untestable: `$this->db = Database::get("default");`

Comment: OK, can you tell me why?

Comment: You have just [tightly coupled](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0) the `Client` class with the `Database` class.

Comment: While you are at it also search for the other clean code talks. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **You have an error in your SQL syntax near** ')'

What about looking at your query near `)`?

It seems your *coding style* failed you.

I will **never** understand a desire to stuff as much operators in one single line as possible.
Look, isn't it much more readable than your gigantic one line?

```
$sql = "UPDATE clients SET name=?, initial=?, payment=?, hourly_rate=?, active=? 
        WHERE cid=?)";
$res = $this->db->update($sql,$values);
if ($res) {
```

isn't the wrong brace well spottable here?

Comment: For sure i've looked at the SQL syntax near ) ... but i don't see any failures?!

Comment: Really? is there supposed to be any )s? Where is its opening ( then?

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh damn... sorry for silly question, i'm such an idiot....